What condition on an abelian variety ensures that the associated formal group has integral coefficients?
I am new in the study of abelian variety or in general algebraic variety. I am looking for a sufficient condition that ensures the formal group associated with an abelian variety has integral coefficients. I am not sure if it already covered in a book/article/paper.
In precise, let $A$ be an abelian variety over a number field $K$ with ring of integers $\mathcal{O}_K$ and let $\hat{A}$ be the associated formal group of $A$. Here $\hat{A}$ is a formal power series of the form $$\hat{A}[[X,Y]]=X+Y+\text{higher degree terms}=\sum_{i,j \geq 0} a_{ij}X^iY^j \in K[[X,Y]].$$
Question 1: When does $a_{ij} \in \mathcal{O}_K$ for all $i,j$?
Question 2: Is the story same for any characteristic 0 field, e.g., if $K=\mathbb{Q}_p$?
Note: A formal group will have integral structure coefficients if its logarithm has so.

I am assuming following two conditions:

$A$ has good reduction at all primes of the number field $K$

$A$ has CM property by the ring of integers of $K$.


Here is what I feel: (please check)
First case: Assume $A$ has good reduction at all primes of $K$, then $A$ can be extended to a smooth model over $\mathcal{O}_K$. That is, for every prime $\mathfrak{p}$ we get an abelian scheme $\mathcal{A}$ over the local ring $\mathcal{O}_{K, \mathfrak{p}}$, whose generic fiber is $A$.
Now the formal group $\hat{\mathcal{A}}$ of $A$ at the prime $\mathfrak{p}$ is obtained by the formal completion of $\mathcal{A}$. I think now the smoothness property ensures the coefficients of the formal group $\hat{\mathcal{A}}$ has coefficients in $\mathcal{O}_{K, \mathfrak{p}}$.
Second case: The endomorphisms of $A$ induces corresponding endomorphisms on its formal group $\hat{A}$. If $A$ has complex multiplication by the ring of integers $\mathcal{O}_K$, then $\mathcal{O}_K$ acts on $\hat{A}$ as well. So $\hat{A}$ inherits the CM property of $A$ as well. I am not sure if it give any information about the coefficients of $\hat{A}$. I don't know if the logarithm of $\hat{A}$ has integral coefficients.
Edit: To avoid confusion, I should clarify that throughout the question, by a formal group, I meant a formal group (law) indeed. That is a formal power series satisfying a group law given by the (formal) group object associated to the abelian variety in question.

Doesn't the answer depend a priori on a choice of basis of the tangent space at the identity or something like that?

@QiaochuYuan, can you please elaborate?

In your question you don't distinguish between formal groups and formal group laws. A formal group is just a group object in the category of formal schemes, or somewhat more explicitly a certain kind of Hopf algebra. To get a formal group law from a formal group requires a choice of coordinates, and the coefficients of the formal group law depend on this choice of coordinates. It could happen that the coefficients are integral with respect to one choice but not another.

@QiaochuYuan, well, by formal group, I meant formal group (law), that is, a formal power series, which have a group law. My question is - if the assumption of good reduction or CM property of an abelian variety has anything to do with the integral coefficients of the associated formal group law, perhaps upto a choice of suitable coordinates as you said?
